# Upload Azure blob with tags using C#

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

Long time VBA programmer dipping my toes into C/C# and Azure world. I have this code which uploads invoice PDFs to a blob in Azure. I have to add tags when I upload each PDF. I've searched for a week but can't find code to do what I think is a simple thing.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

```
    using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
    using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Reflection.Metadata;
    using static System.Net.WebRequestMethods;
    using static System.Windows.Forms.Design.AxImporter;

    namespace UploadDealerDocuments
    {
    class program
    {
    static string connectionString =         "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=###;AccountKey=###;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
    static string containerName = "smi-statements-invoices-staging";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.CreateBlobContainer(containerName);
    string str = "";
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"N:\Azure\invoices\");
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
    str = Path.GetFileName(file);
    str = str.Replace("_", "/");
    Console.WriteLine(str);
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file)))
    {
    containerClient.UploadBlob(str, stream);
    }
    str = @"N:\Azure\Invoices\Uploaded\" + Path.GetFileName(file);
    System.IO.File.Move(@"N:\Azure\Invoices\" + Path.GetFileName(file), str);
    Console.WriteLine(file + "Uploaded!");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Files Uploaded!");
    Console.Read();
    }
    }
    }
```

I have to add a tags when I upload the PDF. Something like this.

```
    var Tags = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "file_date", "2022-10-03" },
    { "title", "some title" }
    };


_ = await blobClient.UploadAsync(str, options);
```

I've tried this code, which errors out on the await statement and the containerClient.UploadBlob statement doesn't have a parameter for options.

```
BlobUploadOptions options = new BlobUploadOptions
    {
        Tags = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "name", "myBlob" },
            { "type", "blobTrigger" },
            { "direction", "in" },
            { "path", "path1/path2/name" },
            { "connection", "blob_STORAGE" }
        }
    };

    _ = await blobClient.UploadAsync(str, options);
```

Comment: _"errors out on the await statement "_ I did not find the `await` statement in the code you posted

Comment: Oh, thank you. I somehow left that off the last bit of code. I'll fix that.

Comment: What happens when you call `UploadAsync` method on `BlobClient` (`await blobClient.UploadAsync(str, options);`)?

Comment: Error CS4033 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'. SMI_Blob_Upload C:\Users\administrator\source\repos\SMI_Blob_Upload\SMI_Blob_Upload\Program.cs 45 Active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-tags a try.

Specifically you should be able to pass a dictionary of tags with blobClient.SetTags(myDict)

Comment: Thank you for the tip about blobClient.SetTags(myDict). It took some doing, with a lot of frustration along the way, but I just had a successful test.